# Why the facts and planning entities are null workingsolution during planning?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm developing a project what similarly with the example "meetingscheduling", when I have a MeetingAssignment, I want to get its "previous MeetingAssignment" in the same room.

In other words, when I have a MeetingAssignment - TA1, I want to find the MeetingAssignment which is in the same room with TA1, and it should be nearest one on the left of TA1.

My idea is: When I get TA1 :
1. Get all the MeetingAssignments that have the same room with TA1.
2. Get the MeetingAssignments from the list generate by previous step what have
   the less startingTimeGrain than TA1.
3. Find the MeetingAssignment what have the largest startingTimeGrain value. 
it's the "previous MeetingAssignment".

But when I get the MeetingAssignment list of the sulotion class during planning(WorkingSolution), all of the room is null, I got the wrong solution?
Any better idea for it? Many thanks.

Comment: If the room's planning variable `nullable = true`? If it is, do you have a score rule (usually medium weight) to penalize when it is `null`?

Comment: No, all planning variable haven't the nullable=true annotations, and there are not the rule to punish while the MeetingAssignment's room is null. But I print the TaskAssingment's room field during planning, it's not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the Construction Heuristic (if it has a chance to complete, see DEBUG logging), all planning variables will be non-null. If the CH takes too, see the "scaling CH" chapter in the docs.

Comment: I add a field to the planning entity, it references to the solution class, during planning, gets the solution object by a plannin entity, the planning entities of solution object have been initialized